# Populating Time Dimension with SQL script - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Folks,

I am trying to populate a time dimension table with SQL script.

Something like below is expected output.

[image]

& below is the partial SQL script which is not giving the correct output.

```
SEL   calendar_date AS DATE_,
      RANK( ) OVER ( ORDER BY calendar_date) AS Date_Key,
      RANK( ) OVER ( ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CALENDAR_DATE)) AS Month_Key
FROM  SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR 
ORDER BY calendar_Date
```

Could you please help me find the issue in my code ?

As the code is stucked at Month_Key population, I am not done with the remaing code ...

Comment: What exactly is wrong?  Are you concerned about rank skipping numbers, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CALENDAR_DATE)) AS Month_Key` to use `DENSE_RANK` as it looks like all the rows for a month in a year should have the same key.

```
SEL   calendar_date AS DATE_,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY calendar_date) AS Date_Key,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CALENDAR_DATE),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CALENDAR_DATE)) AS Month_Key
FROM  SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR 
ORDER BY calendar_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point for this when you have `sys_calendar.calendar`

```
select      calendar_date

           ,day_of_calendar     - 32872     as day_key
           ,month_of_calendar   -  1080     as month_key
           ,quarter_of_calendar -   360     as quarter_key
           ,year_of_calendar    -  1989     as year_key

from        sys_calendar.calendar 

-- where       calendar_date between date '2015-09-25' and date '2015-10-05'

-- order by    calendar_date
```

---

```
+---------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| calendar_date | day_key | month_key | quarter_key | year_key |
+---------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| 2015-09-25    | 9,399   |       309 |         103 |       26 |
| 2015-09-26    | 9,400   |       309 |         103 |       26 |
| 2015-09-27    | 9,401   |       309 |         103 |       26 |
| 2015-09-28    | 9,402   |       309 |         103 |       26 |
| 2015-09-29    | 9,403   |       309 |         103 |       26 |
| 2015-09-30    | 9,404   |       309 |         103 |       26 |
| 2015-10-01    | 9,405   |       310 |         104 |       26 |
| 2015-10-02    | 9,406   |       310 |         104 |       26 |
| 2015-10-03    | 9,407   |       310 |         104 |       26 |
| 2015-10-04    | 9,408   |       310 |         104 |       26 |
| 2015-10-05    | 9,409   |       310 |         104 |       26 |
+---------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Basically I am trying to build a time dimension with SQL script that will be useful for Teradata & SQL Server as well (although minor syntax change may require in script) .... In the provided answer, I am not sure why you are subtracting figures from columns ? ex:- day_of_calendar     - 32872    as day_key

Comment: The Teradata calendar table starts from 1900-01-01. The substraction is in order to match it to your requiered results